# Scala Tuple to String (using mkString)

Tags: scala

Suppose I have a list of tuples

```
('a', 1), ('b', 2)...
```

How would one get about converting it to a String in the format

```
a 1
b 2
```

I tried using `collection.map(_.mkString('\t'))` However I'm getting an error since essentially I'm applying the operation to a tuple instead of a list. Using `flatMap` didn't help either

Answer (score 32, accepted):

For `Tuple2` you can use:

```
val list = List(("1", 4), ("dfg", 67))
list.map { case (str, int) => s"$str $int"}
```

For any tuples try this code:

```
val list = List[Product](("dfsgd", 234), ("345345", 345, 456456))

list.map { tuple => 
  tuple.productIterator.mkString("\t")
}
```

Comment: will this take care of adding a `\n` after every tuple?

Comment: No. It maps every tuple to string. If you want `\n` after lines use `mkString` on result list.

Comment: I don't think the `toList` after the `productIterator` is necessary.