# Save file without brackets

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, rdd

I would like my final result to be without brackets

**I have tried this but it gave back so many errors:**

```
.map(x => x.mkString(",").saveAsTextFile("/home/amel/new")
```

**This my code**

```
val x= sc.textFile("/home/amel/1MB").filter(!_.contains("NULL"))
.filter(!_.contains("Null"))
val re = x.map(row => {
val cols = row.split(",")
val Cycle = cols(2)
val Duration = Cycle match {
case "Licence" => "3 years"
case "Master" => "2 years"
case "Ingéniorat" => "5 years"
case "Ingeniorat" => "5 years"
case "Doctorat" => "3 years"
case _ => "NULL"
}
(cols(1).split("-")(0) + "," + Cycle + "," + Duration + "," + 
cols(3), 1)
}).reduceByKey(_ + _)
re.collect.foreach(println)
}
```

**This is the result I get:**

```
(1999,2 years,Master,IC,57)

(2013,3 years,Doctorat,SI,44)

(2013,3 years,Licence,IC,73)

(2009,5 years,Ingeniorat,IC,58)

(2011,2 years,Master,SI,61)

(2003,5 years,Ingeniorat,IC,65)

(2019,3 years,Doctorat,SI,80)
```

**I would like to:** remove the brackets at the beginning and end.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [scala tuple to String](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26751441)

Comment: user want to save file using apache-spark api the above link points to scala only solution. AFAIK, its not duplicate anymore. the below answer shows how to save rdd of seq of tuples to csv. which is what OP wanted

Answer (score 3, accepted):

instead of collect and print like this `re.collect.foreach(println)`

you can do some thing like this...

```
val x: Seq[(Int, String, String, String, Int)] = Seq((1999, "2 years", "Master", "IC", 57), (2013,"3 years","Doctorat","SI",44))
    x.map(p => p.productIterator.mkString(",")).foreach(println)
```

Result :

```
1999,2 years,Master,IC,57
2013,3 years,Doctorat,SI,44
```

or simply you can use dataframes to achieve this result :

```
import org.apache.log4j.Level
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

object TupleTest {
  org.apache.log4j.Logger.getLogger("org").setLevel(Level.ERROR)
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val spark = SparkSession.builder().appName(this.getClass.getName).config("spark.master", "local").getOrCreate()
    spark.sparkContext.setLogLevel("ERROR")
    import spark.implicits._
    val rdd = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(Seq((1, "Spark"), (2, "Databricks"), (3, "Notebook")))
    val df = rdd.toDF("Id", "Name")
    df.coalesce(1).write.mode("overwrite").csv("./src/main/resouces/single")
  }

}
```

Result savad in a text file :

```
1,Spark
2,Databricks
3,Notebook
```

Comment: it says that p.productIterator is not a member of string

Comment: what is the type of re is it string or tuple. if its tuple then you will have productIterator for that.

Comment: first try my example given above you will understand

Answer (score 0):

The other answer does not take into account the structure of your data. You have a (String, Int) tuple, so you must do the following:

```scala
}).reduceByKey(_ + _)
re.collect.foreach(println)
}
```

To this:

```scala
}).reduceByKey(_ + _).map(x => x._1 + "," + x._2)
re.collect.foreach(println)
}
```

Comment: Collect is a bad option

Comment: @thebluephantom collect is an undesirable option, but it is the option the OP started going with. I continued their efforts to come to this solution.

Comment: Both such things can exist in the universe. there are bad restaurants attracting customers, for example.